# Converting image with OpenfileDialog

Tags: c#, image, openfiledialog

I need help with this code. I want to create basic image convert program but this program is not working? What am I doing wrong. Thanks for answers.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();

        string DosyaYolu = file.FileName;
        string DosyaAdi = file.SafeFileName;

        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(DosyaYolu);
            image.Save(DosyaYolu, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

Comment: "Is not working" describes not your problem! What is not working?

Answer (score 2):

You choose the wrong *target* path to save the new image to. Also you invoked the `ShowDialog()` twice, which is not necessary. The following code will save the new file with the same name but a different extension.

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string sourceFile = dialog.FileName;
    string targetFile = Path.ChangeExtension(sourceFile, "png");

    Image image = Image.FromFile(sourceFile);

    image.Save(targetFile, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```